# How to invoke event handler mentod added to control?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I invoke an event handler from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647815/how-can-i-invoke-an-event-handler-from-a-function)

I need to do something I was pretty sure should be simple, I have Form with controls and every control have event handler that sets label with correct formating etc.
What I need is to call every handlers collection for every control on specific type.
I browsed all stackoverflow and never saw result.

It is simple application so please stop comments like: "you need additional function called from event handler".

This is what I tried

```
 foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
 {
     if (ctrl is TrackBar)
     {
        TrackBar tb = ctrl as TrackBar;
        Invoke(tb.Scroll, tb, new EventArgs());
     }
 }
```

But I see very strange error

> The event 'System.Windows.Forms.TrackBar.Scroll' can only appear on the left hand side of `+=` or `-=`

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can't raise event outside class in which event is declared (only adding and removing handlers is available). Instead of trying to raise event, which will call event handler, simply extract handler logic to separate method, and call that method:

```
foreach (TrackBar tb in Controls.OfType<TrackBar>())
{
    DoSomething(tb.Value);
}
```

And handler:

```
void trackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething(((TrackBar)sender).Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error appears because `tb.Scroll` is `event` not `delegate`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a `delegate` with the same `Signature` as the Event, create a common eventhandler for your controls and then you can either invoke it or respond to the event as normal.

i.e.

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void  trackbarscroll( object sender, EventArgs e);
    trackbarscroll tbs; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        trackBar1.Scroll += new EventHandler(trackBar_Scroll);
        trackBar2.Scroll += new EventHandler(trackBar_Scroll);
        tbs = trackBar_Scroll; 
    }

    void trackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TrackBar tb = (TrackBar)sender;


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TrackBar)
            {
                TrackBar tb = ctrl as TrackBar;
                Invoke(tbs,tb, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }
}
```